# Static Equilibrium with 3 tensions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, free-body-diagram, statics, equilibrium

[image]

Hey guys, for the question that asks you to determine the tension in all 3 cables I am kinda confused. My teacher said the 2nd tension opposes gravity, so it is equal to gravity. then you can equate that to **Ft3sin60**. But if both **Ft2** and **Ft3sin60** are pointing upwards wouldn't they have to add to equal **Fg**? But that is not the case according to the answer that was provided.

Comment: It seems to be the "specific physics concept" here is "how are the forces at the ends of a rope related to the tension in the rope". That is easy enough to describe mathematically using tensors and vector algebra, but in a first mechanics course students don't know enough math to understand that explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a straight rope is in tension, the forces acting on the two ends are in opposite directions, not in the same direction.

The rope T2 is clearly pulling upwards on the mass m, therefore it is pulling *downwards* on the point where the three ropes join. The vertical component of the force in T3 is pulling *upwards* on the same point.

You need to choose a part of the complete system, and then consider only the *external* forces applied to that part. To find the force in T3, you can consider just the mass (the force FT3 is then an external force on the mass).

To find FT2, you could consider the "mass + rope T3" taken together. The external forces on that system, in the vertical direction, are the weight of the mass, and the vertical component of FT2.

Alternatively, you can consider just the "point" where the three ropes join. The vertical forces are then FT3 and the vertical component of FT2.

Both methods give the same answer, of course.

Answer (score 0):

When they say the system is in equilibrium it means:$$\sum f_x=0 -and \sum f_y=0$$
We start from the known force. 
 T2=45 kg.

The only force countering it is vertical component of T3 which is $$45kg$$ And the horizontal component of $$T3=(1/2).45= 22.5 kg$$
This is the tension on T1.

Force on T3 is therefore $$45((1/2)^2 +(1)^2)^.5  = 45(1.25)^.5 kg - or\  1.118(45kg)=50.13 kg$$

And of course T2 is 45kg.